# How to add two highcharts in the same menuSubItem, but with text in between?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, r-highcharter

I am trying to add two highcharts graphs inside the same menuSubItem in shiny dashboard. But I don't want them to be side by side, but one on top of the other. However, I want to add some text between both graphs.

I want to replicate exactly this, but in a horizontal way and with the specifications above:

[image]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)